# How to craft transfer pipes/node skyfactory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've dived head-first into the brick wall that is skyfactory 2 (First time I've used a minecraft mod). I'm trying to make an automatic cobblestone generator. The recipe for [transfer nodes](http://ftbwiki.org/Transfer_Node_(Items)) and [transfer pipes](http://ftbwiki.org/Transfer_Pipe) don't seem to work. What I mean by this is that they literally don't produce anything when put into a crafting table in the right order. I'm really struggling to figure out what's going on with this. Any help/advice/suggestions welcome. I'm using ATLauncher to play skyfactory.

Comment: Downvote but no comment on how to improve. -_-

Comment: [Tim lost his keys.  Again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a mod called NEI (It's already in Sky Factory 2)
Open up your inventory. At the bottom of your screen, there should be a black bar. Click that and search for "Transfer node" or "Transfer pipe". On the right should appear items matching that search. Hover your mouse over them and press R for the recipe (You may need to press R a few times occasionally as another mod, Inventory Tweaks, also uses the key R and conflicts).

If you have all the components of the crafting recipe in your inventory, open up a crafting table, use NEI to find it, press R on it and Shift Click the ? next to the recipe to automatically fill it in

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem, and I figured out that the NEI recipe is incorrect. Instead of using smooth stone as it suggests, use tin.